# SCSI Inquiry Command

Tags: storage, scsi, linux-scst

I am very novice to SCSI and SCST. I am trying to introduce a new page code in SCSI inquiry command , So for that i am initially requesting for the list of supported pages using page code 0x00. So in SCST code I mentioned the length of the reply and the page codes supported. I kept a printk statement and I checked the same when sending through scst_vdisk.c file it was fine. But when I was checking from SCSI side I was getting my new value entry as zero where as the existing entries were working fine. I tried to decode the problem but was not able to proceed correctly.

Are there any filters blocking the values at adapter layer or (generally where these checks are present) or can you please tell me the approach of how to solve the problem.

Comment: This question looks like it's OS-specific. Please indicate what OS you're using.

Comment: Linux flavour, its actually internal to our school. But I'm asking in general SCSI functions, (The layers which our school has added had no checks i confirmed it).

Answer (score 0):

Do you allocate enough buffer space for request data? Please check allocation length field of inquiry command you send.